# How to replace mapStateToProps to hook useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux

How to replace this mapStateToProps code to hook useSelector? I have never worked with redux before and am having trouble understanding it.

```
interface BasicProductMarksListOwnProps {
   productMarks: MarkResult[];
}
interface BasicProductMarksListStore {
   productMarksState: AdditionalFilterState;
}
interface BasicProductMarksListActions {
   onProductMarkChange: (productMarkGroupId: GenericId, isActive: boolean) => 
       () => void;
}

export type BasicProductMarksListProps = BasicProductMarksListOwnProps 
    & BasicProductMarksListStore & BasicProductMarksListActions;


const mapStateToProps: MapStateToProps<BasicProductMarksListStore, 
    BasicProductMarksListOwnProps, ApplicationState> = (state) => ({
   productMarksState: productMarksGroupStateSelector(state),
});
```

Comment: I found a useful video on Google - it shows you how to solve this problem step by step - https://egghead.io/lessons/react-replacing-mapstatetoprops-with-the-useselector-hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided I assume the following would work.

`const productMarks = useSelector(state => productMarksGroupStateSelector(state))`.

Make sure to execute the code above inside a functional component.

Comment: Or just `const productMarks = useSelector(productMarksGroupStateSelector)`.  And on that note, I'd recommend renaming the selector function to just be `selectProductMarks`.